# How is Harry Potter a distant cousin of Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

On the [Tom Riddle page of the Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Riddle), I found that Harry Potter is listed as a distant cousin under the 'Family Members' section.

Is this true? If yes, please provide proper citations from canon.

Comment: Depending how "distant" you want to go, pretty much everyone is a distant cousin to everyone.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## They're both descended from the Peverell family.

> And then it came to Harry in one shining piece, the memory that had stirred at the sound of the name "Peverell": a filthy old man brandishing an ugly ring in the face of a Ministry official, and he cried aloud, "Marvolo Gaunt!"
> "Sorry?" said Ron and Hermione together.
> "*Marvolo Gaunt!* You-Know-Who's grandfather! In the Pensieve! With Dumbledore! Marvolo Gaunt said he was descended from the Peverells!"
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 22</sub>

This is referring to the scene in chapter 10 of *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, where Harry and Dumbledore take a stroll down Memory Lane in the Pensieve and observe this scene with Voldemort's grandfather.

> His voice shook and he could feel the color in his face, but he did not care.
> "My mum told Sirius that Dumbledore borrowed the cloak! This is why! He wanted to examine it, because he thought it was the third Hallow! Ignotus Peverell is buried in Godric's Hollow...." Harry was walking blindly around the tent, feeling as though great new vistas of truth were opening all around him. "He's my ancestor! I'm descended from the third brother! It all makes sense!"
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 22</sub>

This means that they're both descended from the Peverell brothers, making them (very) distantly related.

Comment: Ahem; https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySoYc.png

Comment: @Valorum that has got to be the most awful layout of any family tree I've seen. I'm sure it's optimized for space, but it makes it look like the Weasley's are related to Voldy.

Comment: @WayneWerner - They are, through marriage by Harry Potter and Ginevra Potter Née Weasley.

Comment: Though I've read the books I didn't even see *that* link. Information density is too high, *gak*

Comment: @Valorum though I'd be amazed if the Ginny-Harry connection was the first or closest link between the Weasleys and the Gaunts.

Comment: @WayneWerner After reading your comment I expect something terrible. Then I looked at the tree. I don't understand what you dislike about it. It's a tree, you follow the lines. There are no lines between Voldemort and the Weasleys. At least not if you respect the direction of the edges and don't go all around. Also there is plenty of blank space, it could be much, much denser. It's even true that people on the same horizontal have similar age, it's so nicely structured.

Comment: @Valorum: So, as someone who hasn't read the series, what exactly is going on between Percy and Audrey Weasley in that tree? No relation, or distant relation, I hope?

Comment: https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-weasley-family-tree - Married together

Comment: @gnovice: in the Pottermore Wesley family tree Audrey's surname is not given, so I suspect that her name in Valorum's tree is not her maiden name. Confused me as well.

Answer (score 17):

The relevant statement is [in a moderated Q&A session with J. K. Rowling from 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) shortly after the release of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*.

> *From reading about the original owners of the deathly hallows, the peverell brothers, i'm wondering if harry and voldermort are distantly related voldermorts grandfather ended up with the resurrection stone ring?*
>
> Yes, Harry and Voldemort are distantly related through the Peverells.
>
> Of course, nearly all wizarding families are related if you trace them back through the centuries. As was made clear in 'Deathly hallows', Peverell blood would run through many wizarding families.

Rowling dodged the question in [a 2000 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm), but that at least shows that the Dark Lord and Harry aren't close relatives.

> *Is Voldemort some sort of relative of Harry's? Possibly his mother's brother?*
>
> I'm laughing...that would be a bit Star Wars, wouldn't it?

Comment: It's generally true in real world that historical people will either be related to most everyone today or have no living decendants at all.  And everyone in the world is at most 40th cousins or something like that (the number may be lower)

Comment: @JDługosz: Might be slightly larger than 40, but I think you're on the right track: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_recent_common_ancestor#Patrilineal_and_matrilineal_MRCA

Comment: I’m recalling from [this video](https://youtu.be/jyknbCLys_8) and others by the same author in his series on human ancestry.  Look up *genetic bucket chain*.

Comment: Along the same lines as @JDługosz's point; a lot of people think royals and aristocrats are very inbred, because they can point to marriages of distant cousins. Really, we're all about equally inbred as that, or more so, but just don't have good enough genealogical data to know about it like aristos do.

Comment: @JonHanna I think a difference is that in a villiage, there is *some* new blood coming in.  Disallowing breeding outside the group is the worst case.

Comment: @JDługosz that's what foreign aristos, new aristos are for. For a long time that would make for a larger gene pool than many towns.